# Need root privilegs in mint 18.3

Tags: mint

I need to run a command in the terminal, but i did not set up root.,Is there a way where i can still run a command in the terminal without root privileges?

Answer (score 1):

Mint isn't supported here. *But `sudo`is what you are looking for. Run `sudo your-command` and enter your own password when asked for password.